# Searching and importing all .csv files in a target directory

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have to scan a target directory, and import every CSV file there into SAS. I am to use separated macros to fix names of those files (they are intentionaly problematic for SAS) and actually import them. I have XCMD disabled, so pipe solution isn't usable for me (the only solution my course provided me, so several exercises are a bit problematic for me). My attempt so far is this:

```
%let path=my_dir

%macro fixname(badname);
    %if %datatyp(%qsubstr(&badname,1,1))=NUMERIC
        %then %let badname=_&badname;
    %let badname=
        %sysfunc(compress(
            %sysfunc(translate(&badname,_,%str( ))),,kn));
    %substr(&badname,1,%sysfunc(min(%length(&badname),32)))
%mend fixname;

%macro importcsv(file);
    options nonotes nosource;
    proc import
        datafile="%superq(file)"
        out=%fixname(%scan(&file,-2,.\)) replace
        dbms=csv;
    run;
options notes source;
%mend importcsv;

filename folder "&path";

data FilesInFolder;
    length Line 8 File $300;
    List = dopen('folder');
    do Line = 1 to dnum(List);
        File = trim(dread(List,Line));
        output;
    end;
    drop list line;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    select * into :file1-
        from FilesInFolder
            where File like '%.csv'
    ;
quit;

%macro loop;

    %do i=1 %to &sqlobs;
        call execute(cats('%importcsv('&path.\&&file&i')'));
    %end;

%mend loop;
%loop;
```

Looking at logs there seems to be something wrong with call execute line, but for the life of me I cannot fix it.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: MPRINT(LOOP):   call execute(cats('%importcsv('\\file1\podatki\Sektor1\Literatura\Tečaji\SAS_macro2\primeri\bad name #1.csv')'));

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

Call execute is not written correctly. Joe pointed out where mistake was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As regards the requested `call execute` line, this will not work.

```
call execute(cats('%importcsv('&path.\&&file&i')'));
```

The `cats` is not properly constructed.  It's unclear why you're even using `cats`, as you aren't really concatenating anything.  It's clear why you *need to* use it, but not why you're currently using it.

First: you have single quotes around the string, which means it won't resolve the macro variables.   That is a problem for you.  In particular, you want `&i` to resolve.  You also, though, don't want `%importcsv` itself to resolve.

Second: you have single quotes inside single quotes, or else you have unquoted text.

The right way to do this is:

```
call execute(cats('%importcsv(',"&path.\&&file&i.",')'));
```

The goal here is to make sure `%importcsv` doesn't resolve - so we wrap it in single quotes - but get the macro variables to resolve - wrapped in double quotes.  It would be okay for `&path` not to resolve (as it's a global variable), but `&&file&i` absolutely needs to, since it's what you are looping over.

The final `')'` is unnecessary (it could be included inside the double quotes), but I like it for readability (it makes it obvious that it's the end of the macro invocation).  In this case it's unimportant, but sometimes the middle bits have more parentheses in them, and it becomes unclear when you have the right number.

---

All this aside, you're making this much too complicated.  Here:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select * into :file1-
        from FilesInFolder
            where File like '%.csv'
    ;
quit;
```

Why not simply put the macro invocation itself?

```
proc sql noprint;
    select cats('%importcsv(',"&path.\",file,')')
       into :filelist separated by ' '
        from FilesInFolder
            where File like '%.csv'
    ;
quit;
&filelist
```

Now you have &filelist which contains all of the macro invocations, and you can just invoke them, no macro loop needed.

You can check out [my presentation on Writing Code With Your Data](https://github.com/snoopy369/presentations/tree/master/Writing%20Code%20With%20Your%20Data) if you want to know more about how that works.

Of course, if this is homework and you have to do the first way, it's fine, but in the real world the second way is superior unless you have > 60k characters worth of macro calls.

Comment: The reason why I didn't simply put the macro invocation itself wasn't because it has to be done a certain way, but because I haven't thought to do it that way. It is way more elegant solution.           
@Joe Why would first way (with loop) be superior for extensive macro calls?

Comment: @Negdo Because there's a limit to the length of a macro variable (~60k characters) and if you need more than that, you have to pick a different option.